# How to fade text in asp.NET/css

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm working on a discount item, and I'm trying to show both the original price and the new price. I want the original price to be crossed-out and faded. I already have the line-through, but I can't figure out a text fading style. Does CSS have anything like that?

Thanks!

Here's my asp code:

```
<div ID="OriginalPrice" class="pricing-price">
    <span class="price-unit">$</span><asp:Label style="text-decoration: line-through"   ID="lblOrigPrice" runat="server">This is a test</asp:Label><span class="price-tenure">/mo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: With fade, do you mean: (1) a light or gray color; (2) a gradient where color changes from e.g. left-to-right or from top-to-bottom; or (3) a dynamic visual effect where the color becomes more pale or more transparent as time goes by? Pleasy clarify!

Comment: Sorry! Uh, probably a light grey color. Like imagine you have a discount code, and after you enter it the original price is crossed out and faded (not as visible as the new price)

Comment: I should probably add, I'm new to front-end stuff, so i apologize if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) for that. Its value could be between 0 and 1, like `opacity: 0.5`.

```
<div ID="OriginalPrice" class="pricing-price">
    <span class="price-unit">$</span><asp:Label style="text-decoration: line-through;opacity: 0.5;"   ID="lblOrigPrice" runat="server">This is a test</asp:Label><span class="price-tenure">/mo</span>
</div>
```

You may want to very the value slightly in order to get what you want.